# Remove newline/empty characters in Python string

Tags: python, newline, popen

Well, this may sound repeat, but I've tried all possibilities like `str.strip()`, `str.rstrip()`, `str.splitline()`, 
also if-else check like:

```
if str is not '' or str is not '\n':
    print str
```

But I keep getting newlines in my output.

I'm storing the result of os.popen:

```
list.append(os.popen(command_arg).read())
```

When I do `print list` I get

```
['output1', '', 'output2', 'output3', '', '', '','']
```

My aim is to get

```
output1
output2
output3
```

instead of

```
    output1
  <blank line>
    output2
    output3
 <blank line>    
 <blank line>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend for your case:

```
if str.strip():
    print str
```

instead of

```
if str is not '' or str is not '\n':
    print str
```

Important: Testing for string equality must be done using `s == "..."` rather than with `s is "..."`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting case for applying the De-Morgan's Theorm.

You want to print strings that are not '' or \n.

That is,`if str=='' or str =='\n', then don't print.`

Hence while negating the above statement,You will have to apply the de morgan's theorm.

So,You will have to use `if str !='' and str != '\n' then print`

Comment: simply _s not in (' ', '\n)_ will work (and _str_ is class name in Python)

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(str.strip, ['output1', '', 'output2', 'output3', '', '', '',''])
```

Comment: You've beat me to that :)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, you're looking for something like that:

```
from string import whitespace

l = ['output1', ' ', 'output2', 'output3', '\n', '', '','']
print('\n'.join(c for c in l if c not in whitespace))
```

Output:

```
output1
output2
output3
```

Btw: I you want to compare string, use the `==` operator. The `is` operator compares the **`id`'s** of the objects. From the docs:

**`is` operator:**

> The ‘is‘ operator compares the **identity** of two objects; the id()
>   function returns an integer representing its identity.

**`id` of an object**:

> **“identity”** of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be 
>   unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects
>   with  non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same  id() value.

Answer (score 0):

`''` is `False`, so it's possible to do something like:

```
>>> mylist = ['output1', '', 'output2', 'output3', '', '', '', '', '\n']
>>> [i for i in mylist if i and i != '\n']
['output1', 'output2', 'output3']
```

Or, to print each individually:

```
>>> for i in mylist:
...     if i and i != '\n':
...             print i
... 
output1
output2
output3
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove all the empty characters you can use:

```
>>> ll=['1','',''] 
>>> filter(None, ll) 
output : ['1']
```

Please try this :

```
>>> l=['1','']
>>> l.remove('')
>>> l
['1']
```

or Try this it will remove all special characters from string.

```
>>>import re
>>> text = "When asked about      Modi's possible announcement as BJP's election campaign committee head, she said that she cannot conf
irm or deny the development."
>>> re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', text)
'When asked about Modi s possible announcement as BJP s election campaign committee head she said that she cannot confirm or deny the d
evelopment '
```

Comment: `l.remove('')` will only remove the first `''` in the list. I think the OP wants to remove **all** of them

Comment: Then try this :` >>> ll=['1','','']
>>> filter(None, ll)
['1']`

Answer (score 0):

1) The expression `str is not '' or str is not '\n'`, does not serve you're purpose as it prints `str` when either when `str` is not equal to `''` or when `str` is not equal to `''`
Say `str=''`, the expression boils down to `if False or True` which would results in `True`

2) It is not advisable to use `list` and `str` as variables names as they are python's native datatypes

3) `is` might work but compares identity of the object not its value

So, use `!=` instead of using `is` along with the `and` operator

```
 if str!='' and str!='\n':
       print str
```

**output**

```
output1
output2
output3
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just **split** will work

```
os.popen(command_arg).read().split()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "and" instead of "or"

```
 if str is not '' and str is not '\n':
       print str
```

Comment: Good point. :) Still, comparing strings with `is` is error-prone. Consider: `a = "abc\n"; b = a[-1:]; print b is "\n"`